# sql and mysql automatic backup and .net hosting

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, hosting, backup

Hello this is a two part question

1) Can someone recommend a way to automtically backup sql and mysql databases? Preferably if there is an online service (free or paid). Would be nice if the software or website could handle sql and mysql.

I am currently hosting my .net MVC 3.0 application hosted on arvixe. We are on the final stages of development and run into an issue that corrupted the db a week or so ago.

We were lucky that the db for now just contained test information but I gave a call to arvixe to see if they could restore a previous backup. It was only until this problem that they came clean and said that there had been no backup of any files for anyone on my server for more than 6 months because of some issue they were having. We never received any warning about this.

This brings me to my next question:

2) Could you provide me with some alternatives to .net hosting? monthly or yearly price is not an issue just looking for the best out there(shared hosting, not ready for private server yet).

I notice I am getting session timeouts all the time while logged into the application butd see it happening even at the control panel so I am not sure if the issue might be bigger than just their backup procedures.

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: [SE Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?as=1) might be a better place to ask this.  I'm not sure.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same problem (and I'm on Arvixe too!)

Answer (score 0):

For a Linux host, if they provide shell access and cron jobs, then you can automate most things.  Your host, arvixe, seems to provide both. As far as I know, every host that allows cron jobs allow at least one a day, but I seem to recall that a few do *not* allow *more* than one a day.

So you should be able to backup a MySQL database by running a cron job that calls mysqldump.  Something along these lines for MySQL should work. Details might vary, depending on how your host has setup their servers. (You might access your database's hostname through a subdomain, for example.)

```
mysqldump --opt --user=YourUserName -p --host=YourHost.com database_name > backup.sql
```

SQL Server has similar features.

That will leave you with a file (a really *big* file?) on their server. You should think hard about getting it *off* their server, since their reliability on backup is, umm, suboptimal.  You can copy it to your local server using sftp or scp.  Copying can be automated, too, with simple shell scripts and local cron jobs.